# Obfuscate Java ant war

Tags: java, obfuscation, yguard

I wish to do the code obfuscation for my ant based java application.

I have followed the below link and added the mentioned ant script in my `build.xml` at the end of file .

Reference link : http://codeaweso.me/2009/02/obfuscating-a-webapp-war-file-with-yguard-and-ant/

It generated the `webapp.jar` in the intermediate steps.

If i extracted that `webapp.jar` which gets created, it has all the class files of my application.
on decompileing it , it gives the actual java file

Is this the correct way to obfuscate ?

Comment: Have you tried to open a class with a decompiler?

Comment: Yes. it was not obfuscated.

Comment: Why would you even want to obfuscate your own war-file?